is variable allowed for sonarQubeRunAnalysis inputs in Gradle build task in Azure Devops pipeline
Azure Devops Server 2022
SonarQube Community Edition Version 10.0
I have set up my Gradle task in pipeline as follows:
 - task: Gradle@3
        displayName: "gradlew build"
        enabled: true
        inputs:
          gradleWrapperFile: 'path\gradlew.bat'
          workingDirectory: 'hide'
          options: '--stacktrace'
          tasks: 'build'
          publishJUnitResults: true
          testResultsFiles: '***'
          javaHomeOption: 'Path'
          jdkDirectory: ''
          sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
          sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: 'build'
          spotBugsAnalysis: false

When I use  sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true  it is working fine. But I do not want to Run analysis always. Thats why I declare a variable sqAnalyis, So I can control the Run Analysis in Sonarqube.
But When I am using the variable, the analysis is not working at all. I have tried as expression as well.
sonarQubeRunAnalysis: variables.sqAnalysis

or as expression
sonarQubeRunAnalysis: eq(variables.sqAnalysis, 'true')


I want to control Sonarqube analysis task for a pipeline using variable.

You should use correct syntax for the variable, please check the reply below, let me know if you have any queries, thanks.

You should use $(var) or ${{variables.sqAnalysis}}for the variable value in the task:
sonarQubeRunAnalysis: '$(sqAnalysis)'   #<---- marco syntax $(var)

or：
sonarQubeRunAnalysis: '${{variables.sqAnalysis}}'   # <--- template expresson

Please refer to the doc What syntax should I use? for more details.
Or if you want to use the expression, you need to put it in condition, evaluate it to run the task when it's true. If the value is false, it will skip the task.
  - task: Gradle@3
    condition: eq(variables.sqAnalysis, 'true')
    ...

